# LNK 2028: Unresolved Token

Tags: c++, hyperlink

I'm trying to compile open source software that makes use of the FFTW library (I'm using MS VC++ 2008). I've built and linked the library files however I am getting a few LINK 2028 and 2019 errors. Any idea to help me build?

```
Error   92  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00053A) "extern "C" void __cdecl fftw_free(void *)" (?fftw_free@@$$J0YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::~FftwAnalyser(void)" (??1FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FUAE@XZ)   spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
Error   93  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000546) "extern "C" struct fftw_plan_s * __cdecl fftw_plan_dft_1d(int,double (*)[2],double (*)[2],int,unsigned int)" (?fftw_plan_dft_1d@@$$J0YAPAUfftw_plan_s@@HPAY01N0HI@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::FftwAnalyser(unsigned int,class music::Parameters const &)" (??0FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FQAE@IABVParameters@1@@Z) spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
Error   94  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000559) "extern "C" void * __cdecl fftw_malloc(unsigned int)" (?fftw_malloc@@$$J0YAPAXI@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::FftwAnalyser(unsigned int,class music::Parameters const &)" (??0FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FQAE@IABVParameters@1@@Z)   spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
Error   95  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00059D) "extern "C" void __cdecl fftw_execute(struct fftw_plan_s * const)" (?fftw_execute@@$$J0YAXQAUfftw_plan_s@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class music::Chromagram * __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::chromagram(class music::AudioData const &)" (?chromagram@FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FUAEPAVChromagram@2@ABVAudioData@2@@Z)    spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
Error   96  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000669) "extern "C" void __cdecl fftw_destroy_plan(struct fftw_plan_s *)" (?fftw_destroy_plan@@$$J0YAXPAUfftw_plan_s@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::~FftwAnalyser(void)" (??1FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FUAE@XZ)    spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
Error   97  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cdecl fftw_free(void *)" (?fftw_free@@$$J0YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::~FftwAnalyser(void)" (??1FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FUAE@XZ)    spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
Error   98  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cdecl fftw_destroy_plan(struct fftw_plan_s *)" (?fftw_destroy_plan@@$$J0YAXPAUfftw_plan_s@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::~FftwAnalyser(void)" (??1FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FUAE@XZ) spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
Error   99  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" struct fftw_plan_s * __cdecl fftw_plan_dft_1d(int,double (*)[2],double (*)[2],int,unsigned int)" (?fftw_plan_dft_1d@@$$J0YAPAUfftw_plan_s@@HPAY01N0HI@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::FftwAnalyser(unsigned int,class music::Parameters const &)" (??0FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FQAE@IABVParameters@1@@Z)  spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
Error   100 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void * __cdecl fftw_malloc(unsigned int)" (?fftw_malloc@@$$J0YAPAXI@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::FftwAnalyser(unsigned int,class music::Parameters const &)" (??0FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FQAE@IABVParameters@1@@Z)    spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
Error   101 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cdecl fftw_execute(struct fftw_plan_s * const)" (?fftw_execute@@$$J0YAXQAUfftw_plan_s@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class music::Chromagram * __thiscall music::FftwAnalyser::chromagram(class music::AudioData const &)" (?chromagram@FftwAnalyser@music@@$$FUAEPAVChromagram@2@ABVAudioData@2@@Z) spectrumanalyserfftw.obj
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that .dll or .lib (if you've built static FFTW library) files are in the same directory with your .exe file.

Comment: I put both the 3 lib files libfftw3-3.lib, libfftw3f-3.lib, libfftw3l-3.lib and their DLL's into the project directory. I still have the same errors :\

Comment: Then it looks like extern C linkage issue. Try to declare your functions using FFTW as extern C functions, see for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950811/c-linker-unresolved-external-symbol-again-from-other-source-file-obj-file?rq=1).

Comment: You must be sure to define FFTW_DLL in the project files or config.h header or your DLL will have no exports (and in turn be pretty useless).

Comment: Thank guys, I solved the problem. After doing what both of you mentioned the problem persisted. I went back to the page and tried downloading the 32bit DLL's, rebuilt everything, and that worked :)